# Changing div order at bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've an issue at my project. At one of my page, I'm using a markup like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Step 1</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>

      <h2>Step 3</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Step 2</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/RW747/

So, it'll look like this at desktop:

[image]

But, it looks at mobile like this:

[image]

It should be like that as bootstrap's responsive layout. No doubt with that. But, definitely, I need step 1, 2 and 3 in serial (not step 1, 3, 2) at mobile:

[image]

This will be generated if I arranged my HTML code like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Step 1</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <h2>Step 2</h2>
       <p>Some text</p>
       <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Step 3</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gLjG4/

Now, at mobile, it looks perfect. But, at problem is at the desktop, if the height of "step 2" content is high, it push the "step 3" content below much:

[image]

But, it should be like my first image.

Have bootstrap classes or event to handle scenario like this? If not how can I handle this issue properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try offsett or column ordering classes.

Now i've tested column responsive reset, it works for your intent

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Step 1</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Step 2</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
   <!-- reset -->
   <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
   <!-- reset -->
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Step 3</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/9nh86/

Comment: offsett can't help-I think. That class only take a margin from left side. But, I need full re-ordering my div(may be vertically) for mobile

Comment: those docs are for Bootstrap v2; the asker is clearly using Bootstrap v3

Comment: well, Your Editing seems to be what I want. But, there is only big problem that "Step 3" is in the right side and below "Step 2" in the big screen in your fiddle. It should be in the left side and below "Step 1". I can't fix it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can style it better, but here is an approach using jQuery

Basically, I've splited it into independent divs named "one", "two" and "three", and used this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    winWidth = $(window).width();
    winHeight = $(window).height(); 
    if(winWidth <= 986) {
        $("#two").insertBefore("#three");
    } else {
        $("#three").insertBefore("#two");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XF6Uq/3/

Here you have another approach. Instead of using insertBefore, I'm using classes.
Basicaly, you float left every div, but the "Step 2" one, you change it to float right when it's "desktop wide"

http://jsfiddle.net/hige/3TPec/

Hope it helps!

Comment: At the desktop, your div are showed like Step 1 | Step 3. and step 2 is below of step 1. But, it should be Step 1 | Step 2, and Step 3 is below of Step 1

Comment: I was in a rush, and just trying to show you how to handle responsiveness with insertBefore (or insertAfter)

Comment: Thanks! It looks great. I'm still waiting for sometimes because I'm using bootstrap framework. They have some own solutions for this kind of scenario. I haven't find any bootstrap solution for exact my scenario still now though, If I find, I'll prefer using that solution. If I won't find, I'll use your solution definitely. Thanks again